# Trigger child function in parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component `Base.vue` with a child Component that is being displayed by router-view. In the child component I have a function in my `setup()`, but I want the function to be triggered by menu item in `Base.vue`. How can I achieve this in vue 3? I can't use vuex for this, because the function uses a lot of google map things and refs.

`Base.vue` `router-view` `Component` <- component contains another component which I need to use the function from in `Base.vue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily implemented through the [Vue Composition Api](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html)

Assign a ref to your child component as such

```
<child-component  ref="childRef"></child-component>
```

Declare the ref in your setup function as

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  components: { },
  props: {},
  setup(context,props) {
    const childRef = ref(null)
    return {childRef} 
  }
  
}
```

You can now call functions in your child component by leveraging your `childRef`, inside the setup function `childRef.value.childFunction()` can call functions declared in your child component

Comment: Important to note: _components using <script setup> are **private by default**: a parent component referencing a child component using <script setup> won't be able to access anything unless the child component chooses to expose a public interface using the **defineExpose macro**_ (from the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component))